# Fullpage.js and fp-auto-height-responsive error

Tags: css, fullpage.js

I have seen a few posts similar but none have answers and many are post dated 2016. Why is it that `fp-auto-height-responsive` and its css `height: auto!important;` hide the content in each `section`?

Example HTML:

```
<div class="section fp-table fp-auto-height-responsive" id="sectionTwo">
    <div class="slide" id="slide1">
        <section class="home-screen">
           ...
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS from inspect:

```
.fp-responsive .fp-auto-height-responsive .fp-slide, 
.fp-responsive .fp-auto-height-responsive .fp-tableCell,
.fp-responsive .fp-auto-height-responsive.fp-section {
    height: auto!important;
}
```

Shouldn't `height: auto!important;` just take the elements content height and display it normally? Can I override `.fp-auto-height-responsive`?

Should function like this (replicated this and does not work for me - no clue why): https://codepen.io/alvarotrigo/pen/MzByMa

Comment: Can you please provide an isolated reproduction of your issue in jsfiddle or codepen so we can see what you mean?

Comment: I do have a few absolute positioned elements in each section. Let me try to adjust them. Btw great plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason I can think of that would create that situation is if you make use of absolute or fixed positioned elements.

Otherwise, as you can see in the codepen you posted. It should work as expected.